# Does "Dying" mean being "Bloodied" at the same time, technically?

Tags: dnd-4e, conditions, hit-points

In D&D 4th Edition, one can only get to a state of *Dying* after getting *Bloodied* first.

If - for example - I have a Feat which gives me the ability *A* to do something as a Minor/Move/Standard action while I'm Bloodied, *while at the same time* I'm currently in a Dying state *and* I have another Feat that allows me to be conscious:

Can I perform *A*?

Practical examples:

[image: Image of the following text]

> #### Unnatural Vitality:
>
> Whenever you drop to 0 hit points or fewer, you are dying but you can choose to remain conscious until your first death saving throw. If you remain conscious, you can take only one standard action before you attempt your first death saving throw.

[image: Image of the following text]

> #### Wounded Resurgence (21st level):
>
> If you are bloodied, you can spend a healing surge as a minor action to restore your current hit points to your bloodied value. Also, you don't take a death penalty when you are returned to life by the Rise Dead ritual.

Comment: Though not required, I think giving example of such features and abilities would help improve the post

Comment: @Medix2 give me 30 minutes, I'll get back with an exact example.

Comment: @Medix2 I added the practical examples.

Comment: I apologize for the duplicate question!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Yes, if you have <= 0 HP, you are still bloodied.

From the Rules Compendium, p257 (*emphasis mine*):

> **Bloodied Value**
> The bloodied value of a typical creature equals one-half its maximum hit points. A creature is bloodied when its current hit points drop to *its bloodied value or lower*. Certain powers and effects work only against a bloodied target or work better against such a target. An object is never considered to be bloodied.

> When an unbloodied creature is killed outright, the creature does not become bloodied in the process. It is just dead. This rule means a minion, which has only 1 hit point, *is bloodied only if an attacker reduces the minion to 0 hit points but knocks it unconscious instead of killing it*.

Any time your current hit points are less than or equal to your bloodied value and you are still alive, you are bloodied. Even an unconscious minion is considered to be bloodied.